# VueJS router meta data

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, routes, meta

I'm trying to change the title and description, tweeter, fb, ig meta tags for an app in Vue JS (single page app ) I successfully got the title to change from page to page by setting it in the meta property of my router.js file. However, if the page (component) is used for something like a blog post, I need to dynamically change title tag, description, and other metatags on navigation change. So I did this.

```
export default {
    name: "Home",
    beforeRouteEnter(to, from, next){
        to.meta.title = "FTW!";
        next();
    },
    beforeRouteUpdate(to,from,next){
        to.meta.title = "FTW!";
        next();
    }
}
```

When inspect the Vuejs tab in the chrome developer tools I see the router actually updated the title value, however is not reflected int he browser window, I'm thinking I need to trigger a refresh an event or something, but I was wondering if any of you would know how to properly do it.

This is a simplified example,I would fetch the blog post from an API and change the meta.title based on the response.

Answer (score 1):

In vue-routers the meta fields dont used it for change the meta tags, they are used it for other cases for example an meta requiresAuth for you know when a route needs authentications

More info: [Route Meta Fields](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/meta.html)

You can use `document.title` and this changes its title tab BUT that does not ensure that bots (google / fb / tw) can read their dynamic metadata because they scan before your page applies them

> Currently, it's difficult to process JavaScript and not all search
>   engine crawlers are able to process it successfully or immediately. In
>   the future, we hope that this problem can be fixed, but in the
>   meantime, we recommend dynamic rendering as a workaround solution to
>   this problem. Dynamic rendering means switching between client-side
>   rendered and pre-rendered content for specific user agents.

https://developers.google.com/search/docs/guides/dynamic-rendering

If you want to use dynamic metadata then you need to use SSR instead SPA

> Better SEO, as the search engine crawlers will directly see the fully
>   rendered page.
>
> Note that as of now, Google and Bing can index synchronous JavaScript
>   applications just fine. Synchronous being the key word there. If your
>   app starts with a loading spinner, then fetches content via Ajax, the
>   crawler will not wait for you to finish. This means if you have
>   content fetched asynchronously on pages where SEO is important, SSR
>   might be necessary.

https://ssr.vuejs.org/#what-is-server-side-rendering-ssr

Then, you can to use the package vue-server-renderer, nuxt or quasar

1. [vue-server-renderer](https://ssr.vuejs.org/guide/)
2. [nuxtjs](https://nuxtjs.org/)
3. [quasar](https://quasar.dev/)

Answer (score 0):

Dynamically changing based on route is easy, just access the document title manually while you set the meta data.

You could do something like this:

```
beforeRouteEnter(to, from, next){
        to.meta.title = "FTW!";
        document.title = to.meta.title;
        next();
    },
```

Answer (score -1):

You can serverside render the index file with meta tags so crawlers can see the meta tags. I address this in an article on how to achieve this ->
[Meta Tags and how to server side render them with Express + Vue.js](https://juanlaporte.com/2021/08/04/meta-tags-and-how-to-server-side-render-them-with-express-vue-js/)